Use copyOnRead behaviour in Ehcache 3 with XML configuration
I have a Spring Boot application using Ehcache 3.6. I'm using an XML file (ehcache.xml) to configure the cache.
I want to enable to enable the copyOnRead behaviour described in the documentation here: https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/configuration/configuration.html#copyonread-and-copyonwrite-cache-configuration

A cache can be configured to copy the data, rather than return reference to it on get or put. This is configured using the copyOnRead and copyOnWrite attributes of cache and defaultCache elements in your configuration [...]

However, this is the documentation for Ehcache 2.8. When I look at the equivalent documentation for Ehcache 3.6 (https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.6/xml.html), I'm unable to find information on the copyOnRead behaviour.
Is it still possible to enable the copyOnRead behaviour from the XML configuration file in Ehcache 3? If yes, how?
